# How can I convert all empty cells in a selection to have a value of NULL?

Tags: vba, excel

I have a `Selection` which could be any random range ,  e.g. `("A1:O10")`

I need to make sure that all cells within this range that are blank get a value of `NULL`.

How can I do this ?

```
For Each c In Selection.Cells
        If Abs(c.Value) = "" Then c.Value = "NULL"
Next
```

Comment: ABS(c.value) ? You mean TRIM(c.value) or isempty(c.value)  right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do the trick

```
Sub BlankToNull()
    For Each cell In Selection
        If Not IsError(cell.Value) Then
            If cell.Value = vbNullString Then cell.Value = "NULL"
        End If
    Next cell
End Sub
```

Comment: it will trigger a Type mismath error when any cell in selection contains error (like #N/A, or #DIV/0!). You should aslo add check: `If not IsError(cell) then...`

Comment: Dont need that if you use isempty(cell)

Comment: @simoco Good point. I have updated the code to take that into account.

Comment: if isempty(cell) then cell.value="NULL" - you don't need to test iserror

Comment: @CRondao: Kindly post your comment as an answer as well, if you feel so inclined as it is also a good approach, one of many that's possible. :)

Answer (score 5):

**Edit:** was proposed as an answer, but leaving this here as how **not** to do it (based on simoco's observation about SpecialCells and UsedRange)

```
On Error Resume Next
Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Value = "NULL"
On Error Goto 0
```

Fixed for SpecialCells "otchas:

- SpecialCells only works within the sheet's UsedRange (even if you've selected cells outside that range)
- SpecialCells doesn't work with a single-cell selection: it will automatically expand to the full sheet in this case

Assuming a single-area selection:

```
With Selection
    With .Cells(.Cells.Count)
        If Not .HasFormula And Len(.Value) = 0 Then
            .Value = "NULL"
        End If
    End With
    If .Cells.Count = 1 Then Exit Sub  
    On Error Resume Next
    .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Value = "NULL"
    On Error GoTo 0
End With
```

From Siddharth Rout: one more way which doesn't use looping

```
Sub Sample()
    With ActiveSheet
        '~~> How like is that the bottom right cell is filled????
        '~~> Excel 2007+ - XFD1048576
        '~~> Excel 2003 - IV65536
        .Cells(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count) = "A"

        If Selection.Cells.Count < 2 Then
            If Selection.Value = "" Then Selection.Value = "NULL"
        Else
            On Error Resume Next
            Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Value = "NULL"
            On Error GoTo 0
        End If
        .Cells(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count).ClearContents
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Tim, I've already tested this approach, unfortunalelly it works only with cells from UsedRange..Try to select, say `A10000:B10000` (range that is outside of UsedRange), and evaluate the macro. It will do nothing

Comment: @SiddharthRout - no problem - go ahead

Comment: + 1 As this is much more faster than looping! And it is very unlikely that the bottom right cell will be filled. At least I have never seen that happen till date.